# Cannot deliver mail from Laravel to Office 365 accounts

Tags: laravel, email, office365

I have an SMTP mail setup on Laravel 8 which works fine sending to Gmail and other hosts but refuses to arrive at Office 365 based accounts. Specifically we cannot get password resets to arrive. I've tested the outgoing email in spam scorers with no issues, DKIM/SPF etc is all set.

Email sent from the same domain with a mail client arrive fine, it's just Laravel's mailer that won't arrive.

Relevant config/mail settings are driver=smtp, encryption=tls, port=465. The emails seem to show as delivered when I track delivery but do not appear in any 365 mailboxes.

Comment: _"when I track delivery"_ - how are you tracking delivery, exactly? Have you contacted Office 365 support to investigate? Are you connecting directly to Office 365's incoming SMTP receiver from your own code or are you using an intermediary outbound SMTP server?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Email is being sent from a WHM based server email account via SMTP. Tracking delivery done via cPanel's track delivery function.

Comment: I'll bet it's Office 365 doing _silent_ filtering of all incoming SMTP from known shared webhosts, as that's still a common source of spam (e.g. from hijacked WordPress/PHP installations). Is your webhost a _big name_ (like HostGator, GoDaddy, etc?)? If so, contact them for assistance - otherwise you should use a "trusted" SMTP gateway provider such as SendGrid (now owned by Twilio) [which has a free tier](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) (but limited to 100 emails/day)

Comment: Also ask your Office 365 customer's admins to do a Message Trace: see https://4sysops.com/forums/topic/office-365-silently-deletes-business-emails/ and https://protection.office.com/messagetrace